# Variation of Law of Iterated Expectation

Tags: probability

What is $\mathbb{E}\left[y \mathbb{E}\left[ y|x \right] \right]$?

My attempt:

$\mathbb{E}\left[y \mathbb{E}\left[ y|x \right] \right]$ = $\int\int y \mathbb{E}\left[y|X=x \right]f_{x,y}(x,y) dxdy $ 
= $\int \int y^2 \frac{1}{f_x(x)} \int  f_{x,y}(x,y)dy f_{x,y}(x,y)dx dy $ = $\int \int y^2 f_{x,y}(x,y)dxdy$
= $\mathbb{E}\left[ y^2\right]$

Comment: This is not correct - you move a $y$ out of a $dy$ integral to get the $y^2$

Answer (score 2):

Well, your attempt is not right and there are a lot of counter examples.
For example, take $X=1$ a.s. and $Y\sim \mathcal N(0,1)$.
Then
$$
\Bbb E [Y^2]=1, \quad \Bbb E\bigl[Y \cdot \Bbb E[Y\mid X]\bigr] =\Bbb E\bigl[Y \cdot \Bbb E[Y]\bigr] = \Bbb E [Y]^2=0. 
$$

Without any further information on $X$ and $Y$ you can always get the following expression.
$$
\Bbb E\bigl[Y \cdot \Bbb E[Y\mid X]\bigr] = \Bbb E\Bigl[ \Bbb E\bigl[Y \cdot \Bbb E[Y\mid X] \mid X \bigr] \Bigr] = \Bbb E\Bigl[ \Bbb E\bigl[Y  \Bbb  \mid X \bigr]\cdot \Bbb E\bigl[Y\mid X\bigr]\Bigr] = \Bbb E\Bigl[ \Bbb E\bigl[Y  \Bbb  \mid X \bigr]^2\Bigr].
$$